# Plotting Basic Time Series Data in R - Not Plotting Correctly

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot some time series data. My plot looks like the following: 
[image: Plot displaying date on y axis?]

I'm uncertain as to why it displays the date as such. I'm using R Markdown in R studio. Below is my code:

```
agemployment<-read.csv("Employment-Level1.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Tried to change the class of Date:
    `as.Date(as.character(agemployment$Date),format="%m%d%Y")`

That did nothing. Rest of code here:

```
`attach(agemployment)
 View(agemployment)
 head(agemployment)

 agemployment<-ts(agemployment,frequency=12,start=c(2008, 1))

 plot(agemployment, col="black", main="Agriculture Employment Level", 
     ylab="Total Employment Level (Thousands)", ylim=c(0, 250),lwd=2, 
     xaxs="i", yaxs="i", lty=1)'
```

This produces the above plot. I'm uncertain what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

EDIT:

Data here:

[image: First five entries out of 121 entries]

Comment: could you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issues are somehow driven by `attach`, generally attaching data frames is not a good practice. The following super-simple code worked for me:

```
# small dataset from your example, I use package readr to load it as data frame
df = readr::read_csv("DATE,Employment
1/1/2008,1245
2/1/2008,1280
3/1/2008,1343
4/1/2008,1251
5/1/2008,1236
6/1/2008,1265")
ts <- ts(data = df$Employment, frequency = 12, start = c(2008, 1))
plot(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the file generated reproducibly in the Note at the end read the file into a zoo object making the index of class `"yearmon"` (representing year and month without day).  Then plot it.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.csv.zoo("Employment-Level1.csv", format = "%m/%d/%Y", FUN = as.yearmon)

plot(z)
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z) + scale_x_yearmon()
```

(continued after plots)

[image: screenshots]

If you wanted to convert `z` to a `ts` object or data frame:

```
tt <- as.ts(z)
DF <- fortify.zoo(z)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "DATE,Employment
1/1/2008,1245
2/1/2008,1280
3/1/2008,1343
4/1/2008,1251
5/1/2008,1236
6/1/2008,1265"

cat(Lines, file = "Employment-Level1.csv") # write out file
```

Realize that by providing an image in the question it means that everyone who answers must retype your data so in the future please provide the input data to questions in a reproducible form as we have done here.